# Why the "Authorization" field in Http Headers in Alamofire set automatically?

Tags: ios, web-services, alamofire, swift4

I want to send my `apiKey` in headers in Alamofire to my web service.But no matter how many times I test it,I still cant to get the value of `apiKey` in my web service.

My web service always return this error,cause cant get the `apiKey` in the header.

```
{
  "error": true,
  "message": "Api key is missing"
}
```

This is how I make the request,I think I didnt do anything wrong,but the web service still cant get the value of `apiKey`.

```
    let My_URL = "My_url"
    let params : [String : Any]=["param1":value1,"param2":value2]
    let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "authorization" : apiKey //<--this is the value I need to 
                                      get in header of web service
    ]

    Alamofire.request(MY_URL,method: .post ,parameters : params ,headers:headers).responseJSON {
        response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

My web service currently is serving for Android and Web version.Both running well,but I really no idea why the `ApiKey` in headers cant get it from webservice.

Totally no idea what is going wrong..Somebody please help!!!!

**EDIT**

I attach the result from `debugPrint` here,please take a look and let me know what is the problem,I suspect the problem is cause by the "Authorization" tag in the result below,the "Authorization" field is not the field I set,and the value as well,is not the value I want as well.

But why is this happen?? And how to solve this problem?

```
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60c00003d4c0> { URL: http://My_URL} { Status Code: 400, Headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" =     (
        Authorization
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" =     (
        "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
        "*"
    );
    Authorization =     ( // <--why this authorization appear
        16ebe49c51039ddfbb09e5df8519e755  //this is not the value I set
    );
    Connection =     (
        close
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        45
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sun, 14 Dec 2017 14:20:59 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        "Apach(Ubuntu)"
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        "PHP/5.5.9-1"
    );
} }
```

**EDIT:**
To solve the problem above,I read this following question

[iOS Alamofire Incorrect Authorization Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448677/ios-alamofire-incorrect-authorization-header?rq=1)

[How to disable the URLCache completely with Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535432/how-to-disable-the-urlcache-completely-with-alamofire)

Therefore,I modify my request as below,but the problem still the same,the result of `debugPrint` is still same as above.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.urlCache = nil
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

let params : [String : Any]=["param1":value1,"param2":value2]
let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "authorization" : apiKey //<--this is the value I need to 
                                          get in header of web service
]

sessionManager.request(MY_URL,method: .post ,parameters : params ,headers:headers).responseJSON {
            response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

Comment: Maybe the API key to be sent is an empty string. Or you have the wrong header key. Instead of `authorization`, it might be `Authorization` or `API-Key` or something else.

Comment: but I print out the value if `apiKey` in the console,the value is correct,really no idea in this issue

Comment: my `webservice` really looking for the key of `authorization`

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in debugPrint? Then, trace the chain of functions.

Comment: I attach the `debugPrint` result in my question already @mownier ,please take a look ya

Comment: I think it is the response coming from the API server. Print the URLRequest before it is being resumed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked long time ago, but to solving other persons issue I answer it.

Removing `Authorization` header value is not a bug make by alamofire lib. This key and some other keys are `NSURLSession` reserved key, so according to [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest?language=objc) value of these keys may change. To avoid this issue you must change the header name to something like `Authorization-App` or any other key confirmed by your API team.